# Counting Problem about lottery winning chance.

Tags: combinatorics

> A lottery promises to award ten grand prizes to Hawaii and sells 5 400
>   000 tickets.  How many tickets do you need to buy in order to have a
>   50% chance of winning at least a grand prize?

My textbook gives the solution of 270000 tickets which is obviously not true. Follow the textbook's pattern buying 540000 tickets would grant a 100% winning chance, but we all know we need 5399991 tickets to guarantee a win by pigeonhole theorem.

Can anyone help with finding the correct answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your explanation. If one buys 5,400,000 tickets while the winning tickets are all in the rest 4,860,000 tickets pile, then the person would lose. How come it guarantees a win?

Comment: I interpret the question as there are 5,400,000 in total, in which 10 of the tickets contains identical grand award, but I am not sure. I copy the question from the textbook word by word. I think buying only 540,000 cannot guarantee winning  at least an award since there are still 4,860,000 tickets left that could have contain all 10 winning tickets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in the textbook is wrong, but not for the reason you think.

Consider the chances of not buying a winning ticket. That's $\frac{5399990}{5400000}$, since there are 10 winning tickets. The odds of not winning having bought two tickets is the odds of you not winning on the first one, and then not winning on the second one, i.e. $\frac{5399990}{5400000}\cdot\frac{5399989}{5399999}$. So in general, your odds of not winning in $n$ tickets is
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{5399990-k}{5400000-k} .
$$
and so your odds of *winning* would be
$$
1 - \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{5399990-k}{5400000-k} .
$$
Letting $n=362000$ (through some trial and error) we see that
$$
1 - \prod_{k=0}^{361999} \frac{5399990-k}{5400000-k} \approx 0.5004.
$$
Thus we need to purchase at least 362,000 tickets.

What error was committed in the book? They first simplified $\frac{5399990}{5400000}$ to $\frac{539999}{540000}$, and then did as I did, writing your odds of winning as
$$
1 - \prod_{k=0}^{n} \frac{539999-k}{540000-k} = 0.5.
$$
and then calculating $n$ using the fact that the product telescopes.

This is an easy mistake to make, as the first term does indeed simplify like this, but none of the others do.